# Как засечь сколько распознанное лицо было в кадре?

Tags: python, opencv, распознавание

У меня программа по распознаванию лица. Я захватываю экран и распознаю лицо (допустим во время разговора в дискорде,скайпе). Как засечь сколько распознанное лицо было на экране?Скрин приложил,как это работает.

У меня ОС Windows 10
Версия Python 3.7.4

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os 
from PIL import ImageGrab

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() 
recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX #Шрифт

#инициировать счетчик идентификаторов
id = 0

# имена, связанные с идентификаторами: пример ==> Александр: id=1 и т. д
names = ['None', 'Alexandr', 'Sergey'] 


while True:
    img = ImageGrab.grab()
    img_np = np.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale( 
        frame,
        scaleFactor = 1.2,
        minNeighbors = 5,
        minSize = (30, 30),
       )

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img_np, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        id, confidence = recognizer.predict(frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]) #Функция recognizer.predict () 
    #Принимает в качестве параметра захваченную часть лица, подлежащую анализу, и
    #возвращает своего вероятного владельца, указывая его идентификатор и степень уверенности 
    #распознавателя в связи с этим совпадением.

        # Убедитесь, что достоверность меньше 100 ==> "0" идеальное совпадение
        if (confidence < 100):
            id = names[id]
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))
        else:
            id = "unknown"
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))

        cv2.putText(img_np, str(id), (x+5,y-5), font, 1, (255,255,255), 2) #Вывод имени 
    #идентификатора
        cv2.putText(img_np, str(confidence), (x+5,y+h-5), font, 1, (255,255,0), 1)  #Вывод 
    #достоверности 

    cv2.imshow('Screen', img_np) #imshow отображает изображение в указанном окне.Если окно не было 
 #создано,то создается новое.«camera» — имя окна, img—массив картинки.

    k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff # Нажмите 'ESC' для выхода из видео
    if k == 27:
        break

print("\n [INFO] [INFO] Выход из программы и очистка материала")
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Приложил скрин,как работает программа]
Приложил скрин,как работает программа.

Comment: Вы бы поосторожней сейчас с такими-то вопросами....

Comment: А что не так с ним?

Comment: Тема распознования сейчас скользкая, кто знает как дело повернется....

Comment: если совсем примитивно, то просто взять вермя первого кадра, на котором было распознано лицо, и время последнего - разница будет искомым числом.